How to access the IP address of the deployed app on Kubernetes?
I am using minikube and Helm. I want to install odoo from this repo: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/odoo
So far I have run the following command according to the documentation: helm install my-release oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/odoo
Everything seems to work well (except for some warnings: see below)
Now how do I access the app from my browser (i.e. through which ip:port)?
I have tried many combinations of ip:port

I first tried the command kubectl get all, then looked at the line service/my-release-odoo from where I took the ip and port and put it into the browser. But nothing shows up (This site can't be reached). edit: see below the full output of this command.

I have also tried to run minikube ip (as suggested somewhere else) and use the output IP with a combination of many ports like 8069, 30300, or the one shown in step 1 above. Still, nothing shows up.


I am a starter on Kubernetes DevOps and I may miss something but I don't know.
kubectl get all:
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS AGE
pod/my-release-odoo-7d59f64fc9-r9gpw   1/1     Running   1 (55m ago)   61m
pod/my-release-postgresql-0            1/1     Running   0             61m

NAME                               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/kubernetes                 ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        15h
service/my-release-odoo            LoadBalancer   10.110.50.184   127.0.0.1     80:32385/TCP   61m
service/my-release-postgresql      ClusterIP      10.104.152.43   <none>        5432/TCP       61m
service/my-release-postgresql-hl   ClusterIP      None            <none>        5432/TCP       61m

NAME                              READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE

deployment.apps/my-release-odoo   1/1     1            1           61m

NAME                                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/my-release-odoo-7d59f64fc9   1         1         1       61m

NAME                                     READY   AGE

statefulset.apps/my-release-postgresql   1/1     61m

Warnings after install command:

WARNING: There are "resources" sections in the chart not set. Using "resourcesPreset" is not recommended for production. For production installations, please set the following values according to your workload needs:

resources
+info https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/`


Warnings after running command minikube ip:

W0612 18:39:14.957390    2960 main.go:291] Unable to resolve the current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: open C:\Users\hp.docker\contexts\meta\37a8eec1ce19687d132fe29051dca629d164e2c4958ba141d5f4133a33f0688f\meta.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
192.168.49.2


Ohh it seems like i had to use 127.0.0.1 on port 80. I just saw that ;-). But the question may remain as if i ran it on cloud (aks for example)? just wondering.. because that's my next step!

Short answer: Run this command I found here and paste the resulting URL in your browser: minikube service my-release-odoo --url
Long answer:
The IP you are getting from the kubectl get all command is internal to the minikube cluster. You will not be able to access that one from your web browser. You must expose the odoo service first. You can do this by running a similar command to this one kubectl expose service/my-release-odoo --type="NodePort" --port 8080. Then you should be able to go to http://<your-vm-ip>:8080. You may have to go to http://<your-vm-ip>:8080 instead and bypass the unknown certificate error if you have not installed the certificate in your system's trust store.

First link doesn't work. Also the expose command outputs the following: Error from server (AlreadyExists): services "my-release-odoo" already exists. I have edited the question for more context (the full output of the command kubectl get all.

The load balancer type isn't the same as a node port. Did the helm chart deploy a load balancer into your cluster? If not you'll need to install one. I've used MetalLB before, but I don't know if it will work for you.
